# Trouble incrementing variables in Python 3.4.3 Tkinter with labels and buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, increment

So I have started making a survival game, but ran into a problem pretty fast. I wanted to make a button that should will go and collect a certain time, (as in shrubs), and when hit, the amount of shrub shown on the screen will increment by 15. But every time I try to make it, the amount of shrub goes from 0 to 15, which is good, but then it won't go any higher. Here is the code I have currently:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()                  # have root be the main window
root.geometry("550x300")        # size for window
root.title("SURVIVE")           # window title

shrubcount = 0


def collectshrub():
    global shrubcount
    shrubcount += 15
    shrub.config(text=str(shrubcount))

def shrub():
    shrub = tk.Label(root, text='Shrub: {}'.format(shrubcount),
             font=("Times New Roman", 16)).place(x=0, y=0)


def shrubbutton():
    shrubbutton = tk.Button(root, command=collectshrub, text="Collect shrub",
                            font=('Times New Roman', 16)).place(x=0, y=200)


shrub()             # call shrub to be shown

root.mainloop()     # start the root window
```

Any help would be nice! Thanks tons
Getting these errors

```
shrub.config(text=str(shrub count))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Comment: Can you please remove all the unnecessary code because your problem is in fact, at the bottom which makes it harder to find.

Comment: @Inkblot okay just did

Comment: There's no need to call `pack()` if you're immediately going to call `place()` too. Pick one or the other.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood this, it starts at 0 then when they click a button 15 is added. After a second click it goes back to zero then adds 15. It would just be easier to add 15 to `shrubcount` each time something like `newshrubcount = shrubcount + shrubcollected` and remember to declare `shrubcollected` global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code, you defined shrub in one function and tried to use it in the other when you've only assigned it locally. The solution is to remove the `shrub()` and `shrubbutton()`function completely like so:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()              
root.geometry("550x300")        
root.title("SURVIVE")          

shrubcount = 0

def collectshrub():
    global shrubcount
    shrubcount += 15
    shrub.config(text="Shrub: {" + str(shrubcount) + "}")

    if shrubcount >= 30:
    print(text="You collected 30 sticks")
    craftbutton.pack()

def craftbed():
#Do something

shrub = tk.Label(root, text="Shrub: {" + str(shrubcount) + "}", font=("Times New Roman", 16))
shrub.place(x=0, y=0)

shrubbutton = tk.Button(root, command=collectshrub, text="Collect shrub", font=('Times New Roman', 16))
shrubbutton.place(x=0, y=200)

craftbutton = tk.Button(root, text="Craft bed", comma=craftbed)

root.mainloop()
```

**ALSO** 
After seeing the error you got at the bottom of your question, your variable `shrubcount` was named `shrub count` in the function. Small things like this can completely alter the way your code works.

Comment: one other quick question, for the shrubcout in the `shrub.config` statement, that's the one that makes it so it will increment, how do i refer back to that saying something like
`If shrubcount >= 30:`
`print("you collected 30 sticks")`
i want to refer to the shrubcount that increments, not the global one that is 0

Comment: @SpencerG555 Added in the answer to my post.

Comment: what i mean is outside of the method. Farther down in my code i am having it so that if you have 30 shrubs, then a new button will appear that will let you craft a layer of shrub to sleep on. I know how to get the button to appear, but i just don't know how to refer to the shrubcount that is actually incrementing in that method

Comment: So if you have collected 30 sticks you want a new button to appear along with a new label which says you have collected 30 sticks?

Comment: yeah well it won't say you've collected those, it'll just be a new button that'll allow you to craft a bed of shrub, so if you had 30 shrub and like 30 sticks you could make a bed, but I'm just not sure on how to call that variable that is incrementing instead of the global one

Comment: I've edited my answer. You'd keep the `if` statement under `collectshrub()` but have a new function which the new button can call which will packed once they have 30 sticks

Answer (score 0):

Inkblot has the right idea.

Your shrub function sets the number of shrubs at 0.

Clicking "Collect Shrub" calls forces shrub to output shrubcount but at no time is the shrubcount variable updated.

A cleaner version of your code, that does what you want may look like this:

```
import ttk
from Tkinter import *


class Gui(object):
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Survive")
    shrubs = IntVar()

    def __init__(self):
        frame = ttk.Frame(self.root, padding="3 3 12 12")
        frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        ttk.Label(frame, text="Shrubs:").grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=W)
        ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=self.shrubs, width=80).grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=4, sticky=W)
        ttk.Button(frame, command=self.add_shrubs, text="Get Shrubs").grid(column=6, row=3, sticky=W)

    def add_shrubs(self):
        your_shrubs = self.shrubs.get()
        self.shrubs.set(your_shrubs + 15)

go = Gui()
go.root.mainloop()
```

Notice that all add_shrub does is increment shrubcount by 15.  Displaying the number of shrubs is handled by the shrubs label object.

Comment: Won't work. Keeps just giving me 0 because when that is run it may change the shrubcount inside add_shrub, but it doesn't change the global variable, so the shrubcount will remain 0 on the screen

Comment: use `shrub.config(text=str(shrubcount))` to update the label each time under `add_shrub`

Comment: @MobiusCode I think it may have to do with using global variables, not sure but everything I've tried has worked. just have no clue how to permanently change a global variable with something like this

Comment: @Inkblot When doing that i get the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'shrubcount' referenced before assignment` so i put `global shrubcount` into the `add_shrub` and when i did that i got this error now:  `shrub.config(text=str(shrubcount))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'`

Comment: @SpencerG555 Please add it to your question so I can see it more clearly

Comment: @Inkblot okay i will in like 35 mins or so because have lunch at school rn but i will thanks tons for the help

Comment: Sorry about that.  I wrote that initial code on my phone while commuting and didn't get the chance to make sure it was functional.  I've cleaned up my code, and made sure it works.  If you need any explanation of the parts please ask.